# API not showing in release version but working well on vs code

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

I am currently working on two websites with html, css and JavaScript. One uses the weatherAPI and another one uses TheMealDB API, both websites work well in visual studio code preview, but when I open them with a github deployment link they do not work. I have tried to search for a solution to the problem but have not been able to find one, can someone help.

I read the APIs documentation and nothing is being mentioned about it. So I also tried using different APIs but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.